# How to Insert an array of input field that is type text into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am currently working in a Evaluation system. I have a problem about the comment feature. The input field is dynamically created on how many personnel you will rate. I have an error when it comes in inserting an array of comment into may database and its type is text and in my database is varchar. when Im inserting my comment to database it is empty.

I already check if its under my form and I already check the name that I post and its all correct.

my input field

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nComment[]">
```

php code who process

```php
foreach($_POST['nPersonnelId'] as $i => $personnelId ){
        $rComment = $_POST['nComment'][$i];
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO comment
                (personnelId,comment) 
                VALUES ('$personnelId','$rComment')");
    }
```

Comment: Post the error message that you get.

Comment: there is no error message sorry

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193554/pies-den @Jasper

Comment: sorry @dharman I already change it to pdo thanks a lot @dharman!

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize comment and save in database with:

```
$rComment = serialize($_POST['nComment'][$i]);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

and then when you read from database use unserialize to back to array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: try change structure from varchar to text in database

Comment: yeah it works! but how did it end up in text not in varchar by the way? but thanks sincerely!

Comment: varchar have limit of chars that you able to insert for example varchar(120) means that you able to put only 120 chars, text is:

See for maximum numbers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

`TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT       L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8    (255 Bytes)

BLOB, TEXT               L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16   (64 Kilobytes)

MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT   L + 3 bytes, where L < 2^24   (16 Megabytes)

LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT       L + 4 bytes, where L < 2^32   (4 Gigabytes)`